# React-router's history in react-redux provider's connect function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I've connected presentational-functional component to the redux store by means of connect function.

```
export default connect(
  state => ({tasks: state.tasks}),
  dispatch => ({
      getTasks: () => apiGetTasks(dispatch),
      getTask: (id) => apiGetTask(dispatch, id),
  })
) (TaskView)
```

And now I want to redirect on the other page when getTask has triggered (or even better when apiGetTask has finished). So I tried to use history in the next way:

```
export default connect(
  state => ({tasks: state.tasks}),
  dispatch => ({
      getTasks: () => apiGetTasks(dispatch),
      getTask: (id) => apiGetTask(() => {
          const history = useHistory()
          dispatch(id)
          history.push('/otherPage')
      }, id),
  })
) (TaskView)
```

But it does not work with the message:
`Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component....`

I see that it is wrong pattern probably... So, what is the best one? Do I need to pass callback from parent component and make redirect in it? Or may be I should redirect in presentational component (but it looks strange for presentational component)
Or may be I should call dispatch(switchToPage()) in apiGetTask's promise and implement redirection in the application component, basing on the value?

What is the best solution in such case?

And one related question yet: Is it regular to use api calls in such manner as above?

Thank you, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well.

Now you can assess my solution:

```
---index.js----

export let history = null;

const DefaultComponent = ()=> {
  history = useHistory()
  return <div style={{visibility: 'hidden'}}/>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={createAppStore()}>
      <Router>
        <DefaultComponent/>
        <Dashboard />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

---Tasks.js----

import {history} from './index.js'

export default connect(
  state => ({tasks: state.tasks}),
  dispatch => ({
      getTasks: () => apiGetTasks(dispatch),
      getTask: (id) => apiGetTask(dispatch, id, ()=>history.push('/CreateTask')),
  })
) (TaskView)
```

Don't hesitate to criticise. Any proposals are welcome!